# adding years to existing date to produce expiry date ( SP list)

Tags: list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formatting, date

I have a list of training course that all have different levels of validy.

So

course A lasts for 3 years

Course B lasts for 2 years

Course C lasts for 1 year

At the moment I have a column with the course date and a column (valid for) with the number of years valid ( as per above).

My calculated expiry date field is Course date + valid for.

However it is treating the valid for number as days not years.

Is there a workaround to this? your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a new calculated column in your list and use below formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Course Date]+[Valid for]),MONTH([Course Date]),DAY([Course Date]))
```

**Note**:

1. Assuming `Course Date` is of Date & Time type and `valid for` is of number type column.
2. Return the data type of your calculated column as Date & Time.

**official documentation**:

[Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).